# How to navigate control to top level functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, exception

I have been told to design a new API in my company, and I am facing a dilemma when it comes to coding practices.

My API have to do several checks before they can be run, and often require multiple levels of functions to run.

Everything is fine until here. But most of my check (sub to sub to sub) function require the main API to return, without doing anything. Almost all of my check function have to return some data which is used by the next check function, and that is where my issue is. Because of this kind of structure, I have to return a status at the end of every check function along with the processed data, and after the function is called, I have to check the status before going to the next function.

Sample code:

```
def check1a():
    if some_process():
        return True, data_positive
    return False, data_negative
    #data_positive and data_negative cannot be used to identify whether the check passed or not.

def check1():
    stats,data = check1a()
    if not status:
        return False, data
    status, data = check1b(data)
    if not status:
        return False, data
    status, data = check1c(data)
    if not status:
        return False, data
    return status, data

def mainAPI():
    status, data = check1(data)
    if not status:
        return data
    status, data = check2(data)
    if not status:
        return data
    status, data = check3()
    if not status:
        return "Failed"
    return data
```

Being a religious follower of the "DRY" concept, if feel using exceptions to run the code in the following manner would be best.

```
def check1a():
    if some_process():
        return data_positive
    exception1a = Exception("Error in check 1 a")
    exception.data = data_negative
    raise exception

def check1():
    data = check1a()
    data = check1b(data)
    data = check1c(data)
    return data

def mainAPI():
    try:
        data = check1(data)
        data = check2(data)
        data = check3(data)
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        return e.data #I know exceptions don't always have data, but this is an illustration of what I think I should implement
```

Unfortunately raising an exception in the code to do implement this kind of working is kind of shunned upon at my company.

So here are my questions.

1. Is it really wrong to use Exceptions in this manner?
2. Is there a known downside to using Exceptions in this manner?
3. Is there a pythonic (or even a general coding) method which allows me to implement my code, and does not require me to stop following DRY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be a great answer, someone else way be able to help more.

### Try-Exception:

This an opinion based topic.  If they say they don't like you using `try exception` like this thn they probably don't believe in the *"Better ask forgiveness than permission"* principle.

That being said, throwing an `Exception` isn't bad; HOWEVER catching a general `Exception` is considered bad.  If a piece of software is not running as desired (i.e. in some unknown way) you want it to fail thus you should only catch the **specific** `Exception` you want to catch.

You can find a an ample list of viable exceptions here, just pick one that seems reasonable and use it: [Python Programming Exceptions](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/exceptions)

If you don't want catch one of the preexisting exceptions you can always make your own:

```
class MyAPIException(Exception):
    def __init___(self, val):
        self.val = val
        Exception.__init__(self, "APIException with with arguments {0}".format(self.val))
        
def do_stuff(a,b,c):
    raise MyAPIException({
                'a' : a,
                'b' : b,
                'c' : c,
    })

try:
    do_stuff(1, 2, 3)
except MyAPIException as e:
    print("API Exception:", e)
```

### Alternative:

Another way you could help with *DRY* could be to use a list to make your calls.

```
def check1():
    # List of functions you want to call in order
    calls = [check1a, check1b, check1c]
    for index, call in enumerate(calls):
        # If it is the first function we will not pass any data
        status, data = call() if index == 0 else call(data)
        if not status:
            return False, data
    return status, data
```

This implementation also makes it easy to implement it as a generator if you wanted to return the result of each function call.

Comment: I just gave an example, I don't expect to use a general exception for my solution. It was only a way to give an example.

Comment: I came back to my answer to add another example, and I realized you had done the same!

Answer (score 2):

[The answer by Error - Syntactical Remorse is a good one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55677532/1057102). Use exceptions that are defined by your API to handle control  flow. To further expand on the answer, your API does not need to expose such exceptions, they can be caught by your internal functions as part of the way to handle control flow:

```
class MyAPIException(Exception):
    pass

class SensorMiscalibrated(MyAPIException):
    pass

def mainAPI():
    try:
        data = check1(data)
        data = check2(data)
        data = check3(data)
        return True, data
    except SensorMiscalibrated as e:
        return False, data
```

What's neat about this is that any other exception raised by check1, check2… regarding file permissions or process errors will just bubble up and be ignored by the exception handler.

Exceptions are encouraged in Python and they do not introduce a performance penalty unlike other languages that implement them in a different way.